# Storing socket as key yields incorrect value, Javascript Objects. Example inside

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I'm working on a basic server application and I'm having some problems mapping a socket (WebSocket) to a user. When obtaining the users socket by the id of the user everything is fine, however when using the socket relative to the incoming data, it always pulls the last socket added to the key/value pair (Javascript Object).

Below is a (Very messy) **runnable example** of the issue. This runnable example requires `NodeJS` and the npm package `ws` to be installed.

```
var wss     = require('ws').Server;
var ws      = require('ws');

function User(socket, id, name) {
    this.socket = socket;
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    console.log("new user created: " + name);
}

UserCollection = {
    ids: {},
    sockets: {},
    fetch: function(param) {
        if(param instanceof ws)
            return UserCollection.sockets[param];
        else
            return UserCollection.ids[param];
    },
    put: function(user) {
        UserCollection.sockets[user.socket] = user;
        UserCollection.ids[user.id] = user;
    },
    remove: function(user) {
        if(user === undefined && user == null) return;
        delete UserCollection.sockets[user.socket];
        delete UserCollection.ids[user.id];a
    }
};

var Names = [
    'Chris',
    'Mike'
];

var server          = new wss({port:8080});
server.on('connection', registerSocketEvents);

var chris = new Client(0);
var mike =  new Client(1);

setTimeout(function() {
    chris.send();
}, 2500);

setTimeout(function() {
    mike.send();
}, 3500);

function registerSocketEvents(socket) {

    /**
    * Called whenever the server receives data from a client.
    */
    socket.on('message', function incoming(expectedJson) {
        var data = JSON.parse(expectedJson);
        var req = data.req;

        if(req == 1) {
            // login
            UserCollection.put(new User(socket, data.id, Names[data.id]));
        } else if(req == 2) {
            // test
            console.log("Data received from: (" + UserCollection.fetch(data.id).id + " | " + UserCollection.fetch(socket).id + ") - (" + UserCollection.fetch(data.id).name + " | " + UserCollection.fetch(socket).name + ")");
        }

    });

    /**
    * Called whenever the server loses connection to a client.
    */
    socket.on('close', function close() {
    });
}

function Client(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.socket = new ws('ws://localhost:8080');
    var self = this;
    this.socket.on('open', function() {
        self.socket.send(JSON.stringify({req: 1, id: id}));
    });

    this.send = function() {
        this.socket.send(JSON.stringify({req: 2, id: this.id}));
    }
}
```

The results yielded by running this application are as follows:

```
new user created: Chris
new user created: Mike
Data received from: (0 | 1) - (Chris | Mike)
Data received from: (1 | 1) - (Mike | Mike)
```

The results are ordered formatted like so:

```
console.log("Data received from: (" + UserCollection.fetch(data.id).id + " | " + UserCollection.fetch(socket).id + ") - (" + UserCollection.fetch(data.id).name + " | " + UserCollection.fetch(socket).name + ")");
```

Data is sent in order (Chris -> Mike)

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, object property identifiers are strings, and using an object in a bracket notation to access a property results in "stringification" of the object and using that as the property name. In the case of a socket object, you'd probably get the same sitting for all instancess, and hence the same value.

A simple solution for this is to use the [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) or [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) object that allow using objects as keys.